# Undefined control sequence in TikZ braces

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \foreach \i[count=\t from 0] in {16,...,23}
  {
    \path (\t+0.25,1) coordinate (P\i);
    \fill (P\i) circle (2pt);
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this results in

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\UseTextAccent ...up \@firstofone \let \@curr@enc 
                                              \cf@encoding \@use@text@en...
l.14   }
```

Why does TeX have a problem with the closing brace in Line 14? It is just used to close the `foreach`.

Comment: With TexLive 2013 and pgf 3.0 it just runs fine at me. No error. How do you build?

Comment: @moospit Using pdflatex on Ubuntu... `tex --version` returns `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)` and pgf 2.0

Comment: What command do you use (e.g `pdflatex` or `latex`) to build your document? Also insert `\pgfversion` in your document to get the version of `pgf` you are running.

Comment: @moospit Using `pdflatex`, and pgf 2.0

Comment: Hm okay. Need to rebuild your tex-setup to get closer to this. What you also could try is: `\fill({P\i}) circle (2pt);` on line 13.

Comment: @moospit Will try that later, as I need to leave. If it gets too complicated, I'll probably just remove the `foreach` and write each line individually. Anyway, thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments i got that you're running TexLive 2009 with pgf **2.0** - Depending on the package information this is an Ubuntu 10.04 (no support for clients anymore). For the test i installed the server edition and ran some tests.

It looks like this installation is so outdated (had no looks at the changelogs yet), that there's no proper support for the `[count=...]` function in the `\foreach` loop.

I also gave it another shot by using `\foreach \i\t in {16/0,17/1,...}` but this also raised errors.

Now there are the following solutions:

1. Get your system up to date - unless you are using Ubuntu 10.04 Server which still has a little support left
2. Update your Texlive-installation (`pgf` is missing many features)
3. If there's no way you can update your system, avoid the `[count=...]`

If the code from your question is everything you want to draw, you can simplify it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {16,...,23} {
   \fill (\i+0.25,1) circle (2pt);
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> To sum it all up. Do you a favor and update your OS/Latex-installation.

If there's no way of doing an upgrade, you could explain why you need the `count` in the `\foreach`-loop. Then we can try to get another solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I needed the `count` in order to name another variable. (Your current code would start the variable `i` from 16.) But I think I can just rescale by doing `\fill (\i-15.75,1)`?

Comment: This would have been my next answer ;) Just calculate the needed values in the `\foreach` if you need them.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.